# How to post PUT request under the Windows using curl?

Tags: windows, http, command-line, curl

I need to post XML data via curl.exe under windows using PUT request.

In the curl help I found:

```
-d/--data <data>   HTTP POST data (H)
```

What should I supply for `<data>`?

Comment: Haven't used curl with this option, but according to manual, it is simply string that is passed to the server as entity body. If your data starts with '@', then what follows is name of file that will be read and sent to the server. Check man page: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: @Peter Štibraný Thanks! overlooked this - though that this is something specific for unix command line syntax and there is no in windows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

curl sample calls

```
# with inlining plain data
curl -X PUT -d "payload" http://localhost
# referrring file
curl -X PUT -d @myXmlFile.xml http://localhost
```

If your windows curl-port does not support it go for [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). It is a linux-like environment for windows and also offers "a proper" curl.

Comment: I tried cygwin and obtained error with getaddrinfo. Ran on other PC - all ok.

Comment: so this then looks like a problem with your machine or network stack? The other PC which OS is it, also windows?

Comment: I struggled with posting data payload from file on windows too and in the end I found my data file was in UTF8 (starting with FF FE bytes) so I had to use `--data-binary` instead of just `-d` (which is alias for `--data`).

Comment: on Windows PowerShell curl refers to Invoke-WebRequest which does not work as expected because it has a different syntax. Instead curl.exe is the Windows equivalence of Unix curl command and works as expected.

Answer (score 8):

in windows you'll need to put the @ *inside* the quotes for the file you're sending:

```
curl -XPUT --data-binary "@uploadme.txt"
```

otherwise you'll get weird errors as it tries to use the content of the file as the url:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'upload'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'me!'
```

(uploadme.txt contains "upload me!")

Comment: It was the putting of the @ insde the quotes that's had me guessing for hours. Thanks Paul

Comment: Thanks for specifying that the @ needed to be put inside the quotes.  I've been banging my head on the keyboard for the past few hours trying to figure this out.  Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

In windows, if a double-quoted argument itself contains a double quote character, the double quote must be doubled.

For example, enter 'This is "quoted" payload' as "This is ""quoted"" payload" which is very different than in Unix.

Example:

```
curl -X PUT -d "This is ""quoted"" payload" http://localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

on Windows CMD, curl refers to C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe so you can use

```
curl -X PUT -d "payload" http://localhost
```

instead on Windows PowerShell curl refers to Invoke-WebRequest so it is not working with curl syntax. you can use curl.exe on PowerShell to call C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe so it will solve the issue.

```
curl.exe -X PUT -d "payload" http://localhost
```