# Indexing a data through curl throwing MapperParsingException?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I uesd following command from elasticsearch tutorial,

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d" { "title": "The Godfather","director": "Francis Ford Coppola","year": 1972}"
```

Which produces following error:

```
{
    "error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'The': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
             at [Source: [B@d809e3; line: 1, column: 27]]; ",
    "status":400
}

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Godfather,director
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Ford
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 19
```

Could anyone please help, what i need to do to rectify this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are struggling more in curl commands.

Try to use sense plug in in Chrome or Crest client extension for chrome..

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo?hl=en

It is very easy to use and easy understandable..

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you use the same quote sign for properties and values inside the JSON object as well as the document itself which you are passing to curl.

Run this command instead:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d '{
  "title": "The Godfather",
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "year": 1972
}'
```

---

**Update:**

since you are running the command on windows, the above solution won't work, instead your answer can be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257490/how-to-post-put-request-under-the-windows-using-curl):

This resulting command should work:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d "{ 
  ""title"": ""The Godfather"",
  ""director"": ""Francis Ford Coppola"",
  ""year"": 1972
}"
```

Comment: Getting Error: {"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n
at [Source: [B@18fcb66; line: 1, column: 2]]; ","status":400}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: title
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: The Godfather,director

Comment: if you run it in windows, you should mention it in your question. the provided command works fine in linux (ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, actually i run it in Windows 7.  What changes do i need? Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-d`, try to use `--data-binary`.
Create a **movie.json** file and add json below into the file

```
{
  "title": "The Godfather",
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "year": 1972
}
```

and try to run following command

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" --data-binary @movie.json
```